# Drawing of Quotient Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Question: If R is the equivalence relation defined by the partition {{a,f},{e,b,d},{c}}, find the quotient graph, G<sup>R</sup>. Graph:

[image: Graph]

Definition: if G has edge set E and vertex set V and R is the equivalence relation induced by the partition, then the quotient graph has vertex set V/R and edge set {([u]R, [v]R) | (u, v) ∈ E(G)}.

Vertex set ={a,b,c,d,e,f}

Now, I am not sure how I find {([u]R, [v]R) | (u, v) ∈ E(G)} i.e. the edge set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertex set of $G^R$ is the set of the equivalence classes: the three vertices are $\{a,f\}$, $\{e,b,d\}$, and $\{c\}$.

For every edge of $G$, put the an edge between the corresponding vertices of $G^R$. For example, there is an edge $ac$ in $G$: this corresponds to an edge between $\{a,f\}$ and $\{c\}$ in $G^R$. Go through all the edges of $G$ in this way, and you will get all the edges of $G^R$.

It is a matter of definitions whether $G^R$ includes loops (for example, coming from the edge $af$) and parallel edges (for example, edges $ac$ and $cf$ in $G$ correspond to the same edge in $G^R$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.